# why i have to clear cache everytime running react-app

Tags: html, reactjs, caching, webpack, browser-cache

I'm currently studying react for my final project in college and I encounter some problem that I dont know whether its normal or not.

The Error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Module../src/redux/reducers/loginReducer.js (loginReducer.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module../src/redux/reducers/rootReducer.js (rootReducer.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module../src/index.js (config.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.1 (types.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

The solution to this apparently I just have to clear cache everytime im starting the react app.
Is it something normal? Im afraid it will stay inaccessible by user by the time I get this website online. Or it will only be like this on localhost?? And what is webpack have to do with this?

Thanks in advance, its my first ever asking question here.

((EDIT 1))
Here is the code that mentioned in the error

(loginReducer.js)

```
import { userConstants } from '../types';

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = user ? 
    { loggedIn: true, user } : {};

export function authentication(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        loggingIn: true,//state yang dikirim ke global, bisa diganti jg di reducer kalo dibutuhin di component lain
      };
    case userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loggedIn:true,
        user: action.user
      };
    case userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {};
    case userConstants.LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

(rootReducer.js)

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

//reducers
import {authentication} from './loginReducer';
import {register} from './registerReducer';


export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authentication,
    register
  });
```

(index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {rootReducer} from './redux/reducers/rootReducer';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

//store
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    ));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: This is not normal, please post the full code so we can take a look

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp ive updated the question with the codes that mentioned in error

Answer (score 0):

Here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7261 are multiple solutions to your problem, one of them might work for you too, someone in other place also suggested that this: *deleting everything from C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache* fixed the problem

EDIT:
It looks like you're tring to do `JSON.parse` on invalid JSON format, could you check to see what's inside `localStorage.getItem('user')`?
It might come as empty string and cause `JSON.parse` to crash your code.

Comment: that might be the issue, but im not sure cause since im continuing works on it (perhaps i did change the state in localStorage idk) i dont have to clear the cache anymore